# android mediaplayer wrong seekTo

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I use MediaPlayer in my project and have troubles with seek. For example, I seek forward on 10 mins, but real position in the file is about 1 min from start. Get GetPosition returns value that I've set but not the real position. Also, If I set position to the end of the file it will not be the end and getPosition returns bigger value than getDuration:

```
Log.i(TAG, String.format("%d / %d", mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), mediaPlayer.getDuration() ));
```

And I got the next:

```
12-28 19:22:35.452    1344-1429/ru.darklogic.mds I/Player﹕ 3028611 / 2804689
12-28 19:22:35.784    1344-1429/ru.darklogic.mds I/Player﹕ 3028950 / 2804689
12-28 19:22:36.120    1344-1429/ru.darklogic.mds I/Player﹕ 3029290 / 2804689
12-28 19:22:36.452    1344-1429/ru.darklogic.mds I/Player﹕ 3029629 / 2804689
12-28 19:22:36.784    1344-1429/ru.darklogic.mds I/Player﹕ 3029969 / 2804689
12-28 19:22:37.120    1344-1429/ru.darklogic.mds I/Player﹕ 3030282 / 2804689
```

How can it be and how can I solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it: it's a trouble with the file. If same one is interested in figure out what's wrong with the file, it's here: http://mds.kallisto.ru/kallisto/from_rudn/Robert_Shekley_Specialist_Energy.mp3